# PHP says file does not exists when it does

Tags: php, file

Very lost right now.  The filePath to this document is correct and is in the directory that is being printed by the echo but it keeps saying "file not found".

```
$fileName = 'driver.txt';
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/driver.txt";
echo $filePath;
if(!file_exists($filePath)){ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} else {
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($filePath);
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring / assigning a variable to a file but then including it on the 2nd line?

Comment: I also don't know why you're using a binary/ZIP for a text file.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I was just messing around trying different things to get it to work but I forgot to remove that variable when I stopped using it.

Comment: Ok. Are you on a virtual host? [There's a user contributed note here...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#124052) about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Does your echo show what it's supposed to be? Have you enabled error reporting? Which OS is this running off from?

Comment: I am also going to change the file once I can get it working with a text file.  But it never gets to that point since it cant find it in the first place.

Comment: This is on aws.  The echo is correct, when I copy and paste the echo it opens the text file.

Comment: Go over the manual on [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) also. There stands to be something that may have been overlooked.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Its probably something with file permissions, ill look into it.

Comment: You're welcome Peter. Yeah, that could do it.

Comment: I don't mean to tie up comments here but someone removed the AWS tag I added, seeing you mentioned that in a comment earlier *"This is on aws."*. Should it be added back in or is it not relevant?

Comment: What happens if you hard-code the file path+name?  file_exists('/var/www/html/.../driver.txt')   How does that string compare to what you get using DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Where does driver.txt exists relatively to the file your code above? In the same folder? In folder drivers/ etc?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I guess there is a reason why the tag was removed. I can't see anything about AWS in the question so I can't see how it's relevant. Tags should not be based on the comments - only the question itself.

Comment: @AdamWinter I tried replacing the variable with the direct path to the file and still the same issue.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld The driver.txt is in the same directory as the php file.  Safe mode is also turned off and I have tried clearing cache.

Comment: Why not just do if(!file_exists($fileName )){ then? There's no need specifying path etc if it's in the same directory.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld About the "aws" thing. [See this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960558/php-says-file-does-not-exists-when-it-does?noredirect=1#comment109588788_61960558) that Peter left for me earlier, that is why I added it and someone removed it. No biggie but if there was relevance, then I feel it should probably be added back in. Peter didn't tell me if it should be part of his question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - It doesn't seem relevant for the question itself. But I may be wrong :-)

Comment: file_exists():  "Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details."   -from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake, tried downloading a different file and it worked.  I then realized the  file's name was driver.txt.  So PHP was looking for driver.txt.txt.  I appreciate all the help.